# why does Seq.isEmpty say not enough elements?

Tags: f#

nums is indeed seq of int when I mouse over. Any idea what's going on?
This function line is intended to be the equivalent of C#'s DefaultIfEmpty Linq function.

The general idea is take a space delimited line of strings and write out which ones occur count number of times.

[image]

code:

```
    open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let tests = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    for i in [0..tests] do
        let (length, count) = Console.ReadLine() 
                                |> (fun s -> s.Split [|' '|])
                                |> (fun split -> Int32.Parse(split.[0]), Int32.Parse(split.[1]))
        Console.ReadLine() 
            |> (fun s -> s.Split [|' '|])
            |> Seq.map int 
            |> Seq.take length
            |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x)     
            |> Seq.map (fun (key, group) -> key, Seq.sum group)
            |> Seq.where (fun (_, countx) -> countx = count)
            |> Seq.map (fun (n, _) -> n)
            |> (fun nums -> if Seq.isEmpty nums then "-1" else String.Join(" ", nums))
            |> Console.WriteLine

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Sample input:
3
9 2
4 5 2 5 4 3 1 3 4

Comment: Stack trace is your friend! If you look at the stack trace, you will see that the exception is from ``SeqModule.Take``, this will help you pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, sequences in F# use lazy evaluation.  That means that when you use functions such as `map`, `where`, `take` etc, the results are not evaluated immediately.

The results are only evaluated when the sequence is actually enumerated.  When you call `Seq.isEmpty` you trigger a call to `MoveNext()` which results in the first element of the result sequence being evaluated - in your case this results in a large chain of functions being evaluated.

In this case, the InvalidOperationException is actually being triggered by `Seq.take` which throws if the sequence doesn't have sufficient elements.  This might surprise you coming from C# where `Enumerable.Take` will take up to the requested number of elements but could take fewer if you reach the end of the sequence.

If you want this behaviour in F#, you need to replace `Seq.take` with `Seq.truncate`.

Comment: That is indeed surprising. Thanks a bunch!